# Aggregation in SQL - how to accelerate query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, subquery, aggregation

I have question as I want to sum all metrics by month in my query but
it takes too long to load the data, there is another way to accelerate this query - means return data faster?

```
SELECT
    to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') AS date_format_m,
    /*  to_char(cd.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_format_d, */
    client_id,
    sum(impressions) as impressions,
    sum(visits) as visits,
    sum(conversions) as conversions,
    sum(clicks) as clicks,
    sum(tracked_cost) as tracked_cost,
    sum(tracked_revenue) as tracked_revenue,
    sum(conversions) as conversions,
    sum(number_of_reports_queries) as report_queries,
    sum(errors_total) as errors_total,
    sum(traffic_log_requests) as traffic_log_requests,
    sum(conversions) as conversions,
    sum(campaigns_with_traffic) as campaigns_with_traffic,
    sum(flows_with_traffic) as flows_with_traffic,
    sum(paths_with_traffic) as paths_with_traffic,
    sum(landers_with_traffic) as landers_with_traffic,
    sum(offers_with_traffic) as offers_with_traffic
FROM 
    client_data
WHERE
    date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '180' DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
    AND long_term_remaining_days > 0
GROUP BY 
    date_format_m, client_id
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: postgresql, I added tag

Comment: What does "query loads too much" mean? --- What does it return that you don't want? Too many columns? Too many rows? Values too large? What?

Comment: To "accelerate" the query, i.e. return data faster, make sure the `client_data` table has an index on column `date`.

Comment: means return data faster

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your query presumably has to process a lot of data, which is why it is taking so long.  There are, of course, other possibilities for a query being slow, such as contention for resources.

For the given query, I think an index on `client_data(date, long_term_remaining_days)` might be the best index for the query.